# iterate through a character series

Tags: php

I want to iterate through all 5 character combinations of 0-9, a-z.

I worked it at to be around 52 millions combinations. How can I programatically iterate through all the possibilities in PHP? - like counting up or something?

Comment: lol. no, playing with this - while it lasted
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/bjezp/massive_privacy_fail_quiptxtcom_is_a_site_that/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `base_convert($n, 10, 36)` counting from 0 to 36**5-1, and pad with zeroes via `sprintf()`.

Comment: Quick blog post on padding numbers with leading zeroes: http://www.alexanderdickson.com/blog/2010/03/formatting-a-number-with-leading-zeroes-in-php/ **note:** link is to my own blog

Comment: there's no need to pre-calculate 36^5, just `while($x != 'zzzzz')...`

Comment: Do note that `base_convert()` returns a string, therefore you should use the `%s` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to provide an answer, but kept getting stuck with it.

So I'll post maybe the only useful portion. To get a list of all those chars easily, the following should do the trick.

```
$pool = range(0, 9) + range('a', 'z');
```